# Normalizing nested JSON in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to address a list of dictionaries inside a list of JSON dictionaries to produce a normalized table of its contents.

One item from my JSON file:

```
import pandas as pd
file_json =
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "gin",
        "name": "1085 Toledo Gin",
        "first_name": null,
        "second_name": null,
        "producer": "Licores Caro",
        "country": "Spain",
        "abv": "40",
        "direct_purchase_url": null,
        "average_rating": "6.6",
        "rating_count": 74,
        "user_rating": null,
        "in_wishlist": null,
        "in_cabinet": null,
        "perfect_tonics": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "type": "tonic",
                    "name": "Macario Tonica",
                    "average_rating": "7.5",
                    "rating_count": 28
                }
            ]
        },
        "perfect_garnishes": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "type": "garnish",
                    "name": "Grapefruit"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "type": "garnish",
                    "name": "Lime zest"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "type": "garnish",
                    "name": "Orange zest"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

What I tried so far:

`df = pd.json_normalize(file_json)`

Produces a table, but with only the top level flattened

`df_nested_test = pd.json_normalize(file_json, record_path=['perfect_tonics'])`

`df_nested_test = pd.json_normalize(file_json, record_path=['perfect_tonics.data'])`

`df_nested_test = pd.json_normalize(file_json, record_path=['data'])`

These all throw errors.

`df['perfect_tonics.data'].apply(pd.Series)`

This is promising, but I dont know where to go from here.

I would appreciate some advice.
Thanks!

Comment: kindly add an expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data` contains the parsed Json from the question, you can try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["perfect_tonics"] = df["perfect_tonics"].str["data"]
df["perfect_garnishes"] = df["perfect_garnishes"].str["data"]

df = df.explode("perfect_tonics").explode("perfect_garnishes")

df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.pop("perfect_tonics").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("perfect_tonics_"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.pop("perfect_garnishes")
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .add_prefix("perfect_garnishes_"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| id | type | name | first_name | second_name | producer | country | abv | direct_purchase_url | average_rating | rating_count | user_rating | in_wishlist | in_cabinet | perfect_tonics_id | perfect_tonics_type | perfect_tonics_name | perfect_tonics_average_rating | perfect_tonics_rating_count | perfect_garnishes_id | perfect_garnishes_type | perfect_garnishes_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gin | 1085 Toledo Gin |  |  | Licores Caro | Spain | 40 |  | 6.6 | 74 |  |  |  | 2 | tonic | Macario Tonica | 7.5 | 28 | 5 | garnish | Grapefruit |
| 1 | gin | 1085 Toledo Gin |  |  | Licores Caro | Spain | 40 |  | 6.6 | 74 |  |  |  | 2 | tonic | Macario Tonica | 7.5 | 28 | 4 | garnish | Lime zest |
| 1 | gin | 1085 Toledo Gin |  |  | Licores Caro | Spain | 40 |  | 6.6 | 74 |  |  |  | 2 | tonic | Macario Tonica | 7.5 | 28 | 3 | garnish | Orange zest |